# Disable right click "Silverlight" popup in comboboxes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Hi
I'm trying to get rid of the annoying "About Silverlight" context menu that pops up whenever you right click in a Silverlight application. I've added the usual ways:

In App.xaml
 
rootVisual.MouseRightButtonDown += ((s, args) => args.Handled = true);

and the same for all ChildWindows.
The problem that persist is in all "pop up"-controls like comboboxes and datepicker calender popup. There I can't get rid of it. I would like to handle the right click in a style that I can make implicit for the entire application. Is this possible? Can I solve it some other smart way?

Best
Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was to inherit the combobox and make a custom control like this:

```
public class CellaComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public CellaComboBox()
    {
        DropDownOpened += _dropDownOpened;
        DropDownClosed += _dropDownClosed;
    }

    private static void _dropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandlePopupRightClick(sender, false);
    }

    private static void _dropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandlePopupRightClick(sender, true);
    }

    private static void HandlePopupRightClick(object sender, bool hook)
    {
        ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender;
        var popup = box.GetChildElement<Popup>();
        if (popup != null)
        {
            HookPopupEvent(hook, popup);
        }
    }

    static void HookPopupEvent(bool hook, Popup popup)
    {
        if (hook)
        {
            popup.MouseRightButtonDown += popup_MouseRightButtonDown;
            popup.Child.MouseRightButtonDown += popup_MouseRightButtonDown;
        }
        else
        {
            popup.MouseRightButtonDown -= popup_MouseRightButtonDown;
            popup.Child.MouseRightButtonDown -= popup_MouseRightButtonDown;
        }
    }


    static void popup_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

with the extension method for framworkelement looking like this:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    public static TType GetChildElement<TType>(this DependencyObject parent) where TType : DependencyObject
    {
        TType result = default(TType);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            result = parent as TType;

            if (result == null)
            {
                for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); ++childIndex)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex) as FrameworkElement;
                    result = GetChildElement<TType>(child) as TType;
                    if (result != null) return result;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You need to handle the DatePicker in the same way but instead of DropDownOpened and DropDownClosed you use CalenderOpened and CalenderClosed

Comment: Didn't need to create custom class.  An attached behavior works just fine.

Comment: +1: this is a fantastic fix. Well described. using on a SL AutocompleteComboBox with same effect.

Answer (score 2):

C# Corner has an article for fixing the about popup on Silverlight 3:

[Disable Context Menu in Silverlight 3 Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/DisableContextMenuInSilverlight3Application07242009140404PM/DisableContextMenuInSilverlight3Application.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution works perfectly if you run the app in a browser. Unfortunately this fix removes the OOB possibilities for the app, and OOB is a prerequisite from the customer.